# #1054 - Unknown column with backticks

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I get 1054 - Unknown column error when I use backticks in where clause with mysql

```
`roles`.`id`
```

but it works fine with

```
'roles.id'
```

Any idea why and how to solve it? I need to make it work with backticks to make use of the Laravel Eloquent query builder.

```
select * 
from `users` inner join `role_user` on `users`.`id` = `role_user`.`user_id` 
where `roles`.`id` = `role_user`.`role_id` and (`users`.`id` = 8) and `users`.`id` = 8
```

Laravel - Eloquent query:

```
Policy::whereHas('role.users', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
            $query->where([
                'users.id' => $user_id
            ])->get();
        });
```

Comment: Show the whole query.

Comment: `'roles.id'` is a string constant, not a column name. If you get the error with the first code then you have no column called `id` in the table `roles`

Comment: If you're using Query Builder, it should generate the query automatically for you, you don't add your own backticks.

Comment: You don't have a `roles` table in the `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses.

Comment: @Barmar query generated with query builder has backticks

Comment: You need to join with the `roles` table.

Comment: @VictorTimofei I understand that. But you don't have to add them yourself.

Comment: If I add the roles to the from clause it works, pretty weird that the query builder didn't add it by itself

Comment: Show the Laravel code.

Comment: well turns out it was a pretty silly error,  I had misplaced the get inside whereHas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @Barmar my query was missing a `roles` table in the `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses.
Since I have this error because the query was generated from Laravel - Eloquent I am posting my solution for future reference.

```
Policy::whereHas('role.users', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
            $query->where([
                'users.id' => $user_id
            ]);
        })->get();
```

The problem was because I misplaced the get in the query builder inside `whereHas` instead of the outermost the query builder.